# Possible to set default search pane value in data table

Tags: datatable

I am working with datatables and have a search pane that opens. Is it possible so set one of the filter as a default, for example status = 'Active'?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#controllerList').DataTable
    (
        {
        "paging":   true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info":     true,
        "lengthMenu": [25, 50, 75, 100 ],
        "pageLength":25,
        stateSave: true,
        "responsive": true ,
        language: {
            searchPanes: {
                clearMessage: 'Clear Filter',
                collapse: {0: 'Search Options', _: 'Search Options (%d)'}
            }
        },
        buttons:[
            'searchPanes'
        ],
        dom: 'Bfrtip'
   } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>     $('#controllerList').DataTable( {
>         "paging":   true,
>         "ordering": true,
>         "info":     true,
>         "responsive": true ,
>         "deferRender": true,
>         "pageLength":25,
>         "lengthMenu": [25, 50, 75, 100 ],
>         dom: 'Bfrtip',
>         columnDefs: [
>             {
>                 searchPanes: {
>                     preSelect: ['Active']
>                 },
>                 targets:[5]
>             }
>         ],
>         buttons:[
>             'searchPanes'
>         ],
>             language: {
>                 searchPanes: {
>                     clearMessage: 'Clear Filter',
>                     preSelect: ['Active'],
>                     collapse: {0: 'Search Options', _: 'Search Options (%d)'}
>                 },
>                 targets:[3]
>             }
>     });
> });
> ```